# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cnic' cannot be null

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have been trying to insert data in MySQL DB but I am getting a null value in my CNIC column, I don't why it's a getting null value even though I inserted the data in this column.These are the values (100001, Anas, Mehmood, ?, 03127181279, MALE, 25, 1996-10-29, Bahawalpur, bwp, ?, M, A POSITIVE, CCB, SINGLE, ?, ?, 2022-08-06 04:51:40, 2022-08-06 04:51:40)) i am getting when i insert the data ,in these value after anas mehmood there is a question mark (?) thats the cnic value idk why its giving null

** This is my controller:
**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\Models\patient;

class Helpercontroller extends Controller
{
   
    function save(Request $request){
   
$fname= $request->fname;
$lname= $request->lname;
$cnic= $request->cnic;
$contactno= $request->contactno;
$gender= $request->gender;
$age= $request->age;
$dob= $request->dob;
$city= $request->city;
$address= $request->address;
$husbandname= $request->husbandname;
$fathername= $request->fathername;
$bloodgroup= $request->bloodgroup;
$primaryphy= $request->primaryphy;
$clientname= $request->clientname;
$maritalstatus= $request->maritalstatus;
$emergencyno= $request->emergencyno;
$category= $request->category;



$data = DB::table('patients')->where('cnic',$cnic)->count();
if($data == 0)

      {
        $patientid = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'patients', 'length' => 6, 'prefix' =>'1']);
   
        $query= new patient;
        $query->patientid=$patientid;
        $query->fname=$fname;
        $query->lname=$lname;
        $query->cnic=$cnic;
        $query->contactno=$contactno;
        $query->gender=$gender;
        $query->age=$age;
        $query->dob=$dob;
        $query->city=$city;
        $query->address=$address;
        $query->husbandname=$husbandname;
        $query->fathername=$fathername;
        $query->bloodgroup=$bloodgroup;
        $query->clientname=$clientname;
        $query->maritalstatus=$maritalstatus;
        $query->emergencyno=$emergencyno;
        $query->category=$category;

$query->save();
        
      }
else{

    return back()->with ('fail','Patient already exists with the same CNIC Number');

    
}


if ($query){
    return back()->with ('success',$patientid );
    
}
else{
    return back()->with ('fail','something went wrong');
}

}




public function search()
    {
        return view ('registration');
    }



function searchpatient(Request $request){
    $patientid = $request->input('patientid');
    


    $data = DB::table('patients')->where(['patientid'=>$patientid])->first();

    return  $data;
}

function searchpatientcnic(Request $request){
    $cnic = $request->input('cnic');
    


    $data = DB::table('patients')->where(['cnic'=>$cnic])->first();

    return  $data;
}
    
        
    }
```

**
This is my web route:
**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\login;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use App\Http\Controllers\add1;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Helpercontroller;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/registration',[Helpercontroller::class,'search']);


Route::get('/searchpatient' , [Helpercontroller::class,'searchpatient']);
Route::get('/searchpatientcnic' , [Helpercontroller::class,'searchpatientcnic']);
```

** This is my blade file: **

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 d4 " style="margin-top: 50px">

    <h4>Patient Registration</h4>
</div><br>

        @if(Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{Session::get('success')}}
</div>
@endif  

@if(Session::get('fail'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
{{Session::get('fail')}}
</div>
@endif

    <div class="block border mb-2">
        <div class="card-body pt-2 pb-2">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
            <form action="save" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf
            <label>First Name:<span class="d2">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="" autofocus type="text" name="fname" class="form-control form-control-sm" tabIndex="2" id="fname" value="{{old('fname')}}" required >
                </div>
                

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="lname" class="form-control form-control-sm" tabIndex="3" id="lname"  value="{{old('lname')}}" >
                </div>
                


                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Age:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="age" class="form-control form-control-sm" tabIndex="4" id="age"  value="{{old('age')}}"  >
                </div>
            



                
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>DOB:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="date" name="dob" class="form-control form-control-sm" tabIndex="5" id="dob"  value="{{old('dob')}}"  >
                </div>
                

                
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Gender:<span class="d2">*</span></label>
                
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm sel" name="gender" tabIndex="6" id="gender" value="{{old('gender')}}" required >
          <option value="">SELECT</option>
        <option value="MALE">MALE</option>
        <option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</option>
        <option value="NEUTER">NEUTER</option>
           </select>
                </div>
                



                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Contact No:<span class="d2">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="" type="number" name="contactno" class="form-control form-control-sm" tabIndex="7" id="contactno" data-validate="Valid Contact# is required" pattern="^\d{11}$"  tabIndex="6"  value="{{old('contact')}}" required >
                </div>
                

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Father Name:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="fathername" class="form-control form-control-sm" tabIndex="8" id="fathername" tabIndex="7"  value="{{old('fathername')}}"  >
                </div>
                


                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Husband Name:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="husbandname" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="husbandname"  tabIndex="9"  value="{{old('husbandname')}}"  >
                </div>
                



                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>CNIC: <span class="d2">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="" type="number" name="cnic" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cnic" tabIndex="10"   pattern="^\d{13}$"  required >
                </div>
                    

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>City: <span class="d2">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="city" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="city"  tabIndex="11"  value="{{old('city')}}" required >
                </div>
                


                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Category:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="category" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category"  tabIndex="12"  value="{{old('category')}}" >
                </div>
                



                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Emergency No:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="number" name="emergencyno" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="emergencyno" tabIndex="13"  value="{{old('emergencyno')}}"  >
                </div>
                


                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Marital Status:</label>
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm sel" name="maritalstatus" tabIndex="14" id="maritalstatus" value="{{old('maritalstatus')}}"  >
                <option value="">SELECT</option>
        <option value="NOT SPECIFIED">NOT SPECIFIED</option>
        <option value="SINGLE">SINGLE</option>
        <option value="MARRIED">MARRIED</option>
        <option value="WIDOW">WIDOW</option>
        <option value="WIDOWER">WIDOWER</option>
        <option value="DIVORCED">DIVORCED</option>
        <option value="SEPARATED">SEPARATED</option>
        <option value="UNKNOWN">UNKNOWN</option>
           </select>
                </div>
                

                

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Blood Group:</label>
              <select class="form-control form-control-sm sel" name="bloodgroup" tabIndex="15" id="bloodgroup"  value="{{old('bloodgroup')}}"  >
          <option value="">SELECT</option>
        <option value="NOT SPECIFIED">NOT SPECIFIED</option>
        <option value="A POSITIVE">A POSITIVE</option>
        <option value="A NEGATIVE">A NEGATIVE</option>
        <option value="B POSITIVE">B POSITIVE</option>
        <option value="B NEGATIVE">B NEGATIVE</option>
        <option value="O POSITIVE">O POSITIVE</option>
        <option value="O NEGATIVE">O NEGATIVE</option>
        <option value="AB POSITIVE">AB POSITIVE</option>
        <option value="AB NEGATIVE">AB NEGATIVE</option>
           </select>
                </div>
                
               

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Primary Phy:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="primaryphy" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="primaryphy"  tabIndex="16"  value="{{old('primaryphy')}}"  >
                </div>
                


              

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Address:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="text" name="address" class="form-control form-control-sm"  id="address" tabIndex="17"  value="{{old('address')}}"  >
                </div>
               

              

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Client Name:</label>
              <select class="form-control form-control-sm sel"  name="clientname" tabIndex="18" id="clientname" value="{{old('clientname')}}"  >
          <option value="">SELECT</option>
        <option value="SPECIAL FINANCIAL APPROVAL">SPECIAL FINANCIAL APPROVAL</option>
        <option value="SEHAT CARD">SEHAT CARD</option>
        <option value="CCB">CCB</option>
        <option value="BVH HOSPITAL">BVH HOSPITAL</option>
        <option value="CCB HOSPITAL/INDOOR">CCB HOSPITAL/INDOOR</option>
        <option value="BH-MLC">BH-MLC</option>
           </select>        
        </div>
        
                
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Patient ID:</label>
            <input placeholder="" type="number" name="patientid" id="patientid" class="form-control PAT form-control-sm d2" disabled >
                </div>


        
                


                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-block  col-lg-12" value="" tabIndex="19">Register</button>
                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-block col-lg-12 disabled" value=""  >Update</button>
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-block col-lg-12" value="" >Refresh</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-block col-lg-12" value=""  >Clear</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-block col-lg-12 disabled">Update Contact</button>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-block col-lg-12 disabled">Update Info</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2">
        
                <label>Search Patient :</label>
            <input placeholder="Enter Patient ID" type="number"  name="patientid" id="selectpatientid" class="form-control form-control-sm d2"  >
              <input placeholder="Enter Patient CNIC" type="number"  name="cnic" id="selectpatientcnic" class="form-control form-control-sm d2"  >

                </div>  

</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Personal data and code disclosed. Question may need to be deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. may `cnic` not in `$fillable` in your model. add to fillable like: `protected $fillable = ['all columns', 'cnic']`
2. check spell of variable names in blade and controller.
3. try run your route with [postman](https://www.postman.com/). just write your route and send the request data and send it if work, it means the problem in your blade file, if not work the problem in controller.